# urllib2.ProxyHandler - query

Tags: python, url, proxy, python-2.6

Definition :

```
urllib2.ProxyHandler([proxies])
```

Cause requests to go through a proxy. If proxies is given, it must be a dictionary mapping protocol names to URLs of proxies. The default is to read the list of proxies from the environment variables _proxy. If no proxy environment variables are set, then in a Windows environment proxy settings are obtained from the registry’s Internet Settings section, and in a Mac OS X environment proxy information is retrieved from the OS X System Configuration Framework.

My understanding , if proxy is not set explicity it detects proxy from registry settings .

Buet when I run the below code:

```
import urllib2
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
print "1"
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
print "2"
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print "3"
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
print "4"
html = response.read()
```

I get the error :

```
1
2
3
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

This means the the piece of code is not able to open the website . I am not sure where am I going wrong , shouldn't as per definition , `urllib2.ProxyHandler` , get the proxy off from registry , since I haven't explicitly set the proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't as per definition , urllib2.ProxyHandler , get the proxy off from registry , since I haven't explicitly set the proxy ?

But you *have* explicitly set the proxy to `{}`. As the docs say:

> To disable autodetected proxy pass an empty dictionary.

Instead of this:

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
```

You need to do this:

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler()
```

Comment: Makes sense , But when i do so , it comes up with `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required` how do i overcome that ?

Comment: @misguided: That means your proxy requires authentication of some kind. Whether that's basic, digest, or NTLM, I have no idea. But if you scroll down just a few lines in the docs, you can see the classes used for these, with links to the `HTTPPasswordMgr`. [The examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#examples) show how to create and use a proxy auth handler.